# Arduino - Measuring the time interval between one button press and release - Add Velocity to MIDI Keyboard

Tags: c++, arduino, midi, piano

I hope you are doing all really well, I am trying to make a MIDI Piano Keyboard, Pretty basic I press a key the MIDI signal is send and the sounds comes.

But I want to add the velocity to the my keys, there are one contacts per key (the keyboard I am using is Fatar Keyboard).

***I need to calculate the time interval between the first contact and then the second contact ( Circuit Diagram is attached below).***

- *All the keys are in set as input pull_up*
- *when a key is pressed it goes low … Of course*

Mentioned Below is the function where I am reading the keys. what do I need to do to get the following situation done

**[they are 49 keys which are arranged in to two diode matrices. There are actually 98 switches in the matrix. The reason for this is that there are two switches under each key. When a key is pressed, one of the switches closes slightly before the other one. By measuring the time of flight between the switches we can derive the velocity]**

---

Situation 1

- Key is pressed
- Start Time
- Time for how long its pressed
- Key Released

---

```
Code

        void read_keys() {
    
     for (uint8_t key = 0; key < 49; key ++) {
        digitalWrite(output_main[key], LOW); //turn off output main key
        
            if (digitalRead(input_pullup[key]) == LOW) {
              //check main input key is presses
              //check with key_activated array
              firstcontactdownmills = millis();
              Serial.println(key);
              Velocity = map(currentmills - firstcontactdownmills, 0, 256, 127, 0);
              if (key_activated[key] == 0) {
    
                //send midi on command
                my_midi.sendNoteOn(key + note_offset, Velocity, 1);
                main_midi.sendNoteOn(key + note_offset, Velocity, 1);
                //update array
                key_activated[key] = 1;
              }
            }
        
            else { //if key released
              //check with key_activated array
              if (key_activated[key] == 1) {
        
                //send midi off command
                my_midi.sendNoteOff(key + note_offset, 0, 1);
                main_midi.sendNoteOff(key + note_offset, 0, 1);
                //update array
                key_activated[key] = 0;
              }
            }
            digitalWrite(output_main[key], HIGH); //turn on output main key
          }
        }
```

---

[Circuit Diagram of the Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4pjO.gif)

Comment: Situation 2: You should probably discard that key press. if the user manages to press the key just enough to close the first contact but not enough to close contact 2, it's a very soft key press - and the user could hold the key in that position a long time until release. Don't even send a `NodeOn` for that. Only care about the time between contact 1 and 2 which gives you what you need to send a `NoteOn` with velocity (0-127 if I remember MIDI correctly).

Comment: I understand each key has two contacts, and the time difference between first contact and second contact of the same key yields the desired speed? Your main question is easy, because your loop can easily be faster than a millisecond. Remember time of the first contact and compare several rounds later, when the second contact happens.
Do you need to consider mechanical bouncing of the contacts?

Comment: @datafiddler , No I didn't face the mechanical bouncing problem

Comment: Thanks @TedLyngmo , I think you're right. but can you tell me how do I get the time difference between the two contacts ?

Comment: Just do as @datafiddler suggests. When the first contact is closed, store the time. `firstcontact[key] = millis();`. When the second contact is closed, check the difference in time to the first contact, `auto diff = mills() - firstcontact[key];` - then convert `diff` to  0-127 to get the velocity.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, But how do I check if the second contact is closed ?

Comment: @SaadImtiaz You do just as when you check if the first contact is closed. You need one loop that scans the first contact on all keys, then one loop that scans the second contact on all keys - or possibly, combine the two checks for each key in one loop.

Comment: @TedLyngmo , Im sorry if I am bothering you  again and again, but my question is how will the second contact will be monitored of a single key, like what will be the code for that , `if (digitalRead(input_pullup[key]) == LOW) { firstcontact[key] = millis(); }` , but now the input_pullup will go HIGH and then LOW again ( when the second contact is closed. how do I get the difference of time between the two

Comment: @SaadImtiaz Don't worry about bothering me :) Each key has separate pins for contact1 and contact2, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you so much for helping me :),  I have attracted schematics of the keyboard, actually both the contacts are connecting to a single pin, so in slow motion I would say it goes low high low, so I need time between the first low and the second low, I hope I explained well please let me know

Comment: @SaadImtiaz I'm afraid the abbreviations in the schematics doesn't tell me anything. So, if I understand it correctly, you only know that there are two contacts but have no way of getting the information about which contact it is that draws the pin low?

Comment: @TedLyngmo , both the contacts are connected to one pin, so button is pressed it goes low high low, ( first contact(LOW)  , free(HIGH) , second contact(LOW) ) ,

Comment: Yes, so it could just as well be first, free, first if the key doesn't reach the second contact.

Comment: Yes, you can say it like that @TedLyngmo

Comment: @SaadImtiaz Do you have any hardware support for determining that the key is in the released position?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just need the algorithm[code example] that how will I just can I determine the time interval between a low high low thats all

Comment: @SaadImtiaz I'm trying to figure out a way to do that reliably. if you don't know that the second low is from contact2 or if it's from contact1 - you don't really know if the key was released or pressed all the way to close contact2. This makes it possible for your program to get out of sync - sending key on when it should send key off and vice versa.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I like serial out the key that gets pressed, I get the pin low twice per key, so I am sure that both the contacts are from a single pin. like you said it is first free first so to speak

Comment: Yes, I understand both contacts are connected to one pin. I'm just saying that if you have a never ending sequence of high, low, high, low, high, low ..., high, low and start your program - there is no way for the program to know if it should send key on or off.

Comment: yes, but what if I try the low high low and just find the time of the high time between the two lows , what will be the code for that , I just wanna try it , can you help me in that @TedLyngmo

Answer (score 0):

You can add a state variable to your keys, that keeps track of where your key is. You can then start the timer at the transition from not_pressed to half_pressed. You then evaluate the velocity at a transition from half_pressed to full_pressed.

You should also add a timeout that resets it back to unpressed in case a key press is missed.

But I am not sure if your loop will be fast enough after adding this kind of logic.

Comment: Thanks for the helping, yes it is fast enough because a single key press is almost get scanned 2 loops, its pretty fast I just need the algo to find the time between the low high low  - the time interval between two presses on a button

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea that assumes that if a keyboard player is holding down a key, the contact pin will stay `LOW` and that there will be 3 interesting state changes

- First HIGH->LOW : First contact - record the current time using `millis()`
- Second HIGH->LOW : Second contact - calculate velocity and send key on.
- Third HIGH->LOW : Release contact - send key off

Since it doesn't seem possible to actually know if it's *contact1* or *contact2* that causes the pin to go `LOW`, it's very sensitive. If you start the program while holding down a key, that will cause the program to think it's the first contact - and everything after that will be messed up.

First, you need something to convert the time between two *contact* events into *velocity*. Here's a linear conversion funciton. You'll need to find the proper constants for `min` and `max` for your keyboard by measuring.

```
unsigned char calc_velocity(unsigned ms) {
    static constexpr unsigned min = 2;   // the fastest time you've measured
    static constexpr unsigned max = 80;  // the slowest time you've measured
    static constexpr unsigned mul = 127000 / (max - min);

    if(ms < min) return 127; // harder than "possible", log and recalibrate
    if(ms > max) return 0;   // softer than "possible", log and recalibrate

    return (127000 - ((ms - min) * mul)) / 1000; // 0(min vel) - 127(max vel)
}
```

Then, you could create a class to keep track of the state for *one* key alone. It makes it easier than to have a lot of separate arrays.

```
// an enum for keyboard events
enum class Event { ev_nothing, ev_key_on, ev_key_off };

struct Key {
    unsigned long first_contact{};
    int contact_count = 0;
    unsigned char velocity{};
    bool contact_state = false;

    // set contact state and return an Event to act upon
    Event set(bool contact) { // false = no contact, true = contact

        // if the state has not changed, do nothing
        if(contact == contact_state) return Event::ev_nothing;

        contact_state = contact;                        // set the new state

        // only care about when state changes to having contact
        if(contact_state) {
               
            // count HIGH->LOW transitions
            contact_count = (contact_count + 1) % 3;

            // 1 = first contact
            // 2 = second contact (key on)
            // 0 = release contact (key off)

            switch(contact_count) {
            case 2:                                     // second contact
                velocity = calc_velocity(millis() - first_contact);
                return Event::ev_key_on;
            case 0: return Event::ev_key_off;           // release contact
            case 1: first_contact = millis();           // first contact
            }
        }
        return Event::ev_nothing;
    }
};
```

Then define these globally:

```
constexpr std::uint8_t kNumberOfKeys = 49;
Key keys[kNumberOfKeys];
```

With that, your `read_keys()` function could look this this:

```
void read_keys() {    
    for (uint8_t key = 0; key < kNumberOfKeys; ++key) {
        digitalWrite(output_main[key], LOW); //turn off output main key

        // Do a digitalRead() and call the set() function for that key which will
        // return an Event.

        switch(keys[key].set( digitalRead(input_pullup[key]) == LOW )) {
        case Event::ev_key_on:
            my_midi.sendNoteOn(key + note_offset, keys[key].velocity, 1);
            main_midi.sendNoteOn(key + note_offset, keys[key].velocity, 1);
            break;

        case Event::ev_key_off:
            my_midi.sendNoteOff(key + note_offset, 0, 1);
            main_midi.sendNoteOff(key + note_offset, 0, 1);
            break;

        case Event::ev_nothing:
        default:
            break;
        }

        digitalWrite(output_main[key], HIGH); //turn on output main key
    }
}
```

This could be made so that each `Key` object would know which *key number* it actually is and so that it could read its own pin etc. It could also return an `Event` object which starts by turning off output main key and turns it back on when it's destroyed - but I think this leaves it more open since I don't know much about *why* the output main key should be turned off and on.

Disclaimer: I've ofcourse not been able to test this - so see it as building blocks.

Comment: Thank you so much man will check it now and let you know :)

Comment: @SaadImtiaz You're welcome! I'm curious to hear if it "sort of" works! :)

Comment: Yeah it worked as you coded, turns out you were right in the first place and I apologise for that, there is only one contact

Comment: and I had to press it 3 times to make it work how ever the velocity was not working, but it doesn't matter, I opened the entire keys and checked the PCB , its only one contact which is actually a button, giving a low when its pressed.

Comment: so its one key , so I have to record the time when its low and then map it 
`if (digitalRead(input_pullup[key]) == LOW) {
      //check main input key is presses

 while (digitalRead(input_pullup[key]) == LOW)
  {
    pressLength_ms = millis() ;
    //display how long button is has been held
  }
      if (key_activated[key] == 0) {
       duration = millis() -  pressLength_ms;
       velocity = map(duration,0,256,127,10); // 127 - 10
        //send midi on command
        my_midi.sendNoteOn(key + note_offset,  velocity, 1);
        key_activated[key] = 1;
      }
    }`

Comment: sorry for the format, the while loop is when its low it record the millis(); and then I dont know I can make the sound after that and then release it . I am so noob

Comment: Really sorry for my false assumption there,  really embarrassed.

Comment: @SaadImtiaz No worries - Ok, with only one physical contact, I don't see how it'd be possible to get the velocity. The time a key is held down is not a measurement of velocity. Your `presslength_ms` calculation above should however be: `pressLength_ms = millis(); while(digitalRead(input_pullup[key]) == LOW) { /* do nothing */ } pressLength_ms = millis() - pressLength_ms;` to measure for how long time the key is held down. But doing it like that would mean that the program would disregard everything else while a single key is held down.

Comment: yeah so there is no way right ? , I wasted so much time

Comment: surprise surprise they are 49 keys which are arranged in to two diode matrices. There are actually
98 switches in the matrix. The reason for this is that there are two
switches under each key. When a key is pressed, one of the switches
closes slightly before the other one. By measuring the time of flight
between the switches we can derive the velocity. _ Got this off a github  they guy is using 98 keys

Comment: Confused how am I gonna pull of this matrices of keys

Comment: can we move on chat can you help me in this ( lost place I am )

Comment: @SaadImtiaz I wouldn't mind moving this to chat - but the chat option doesn't show up for some reason. Yes if there really are 98 switches for the 49 keys it should be possible to determine which one of the switches that gets connection. I would read the state of all the pins and log them all as soon as one of them changes (`millis()` + the current bitpattern). With that, press one key down, hold it down for a second and release it.  Save recorded log. Repeat for a second key and save that log. You can then try pressing one key down, press the second key down, release second, release first.

Comment: @SaadImtiaz Save the log for that pattern too. Put what you got on https://pastebin.com or similar and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you , okay sharing the link for the paste bin

Comment: here is the [Entire Code] (https://pastebin.com/YY2uskYf) everything else is working just trying to add this velocity part, I saw some projects where they were using demultiplexers , but I have no idea at all how to use them

Comment: @SaadImtiaz The code may come in handy at some point but what I was more interested in was the kind of log I described above. Monitor _all_ inputs, if there are any changes, log them all with the time: `millis()` + a number of `0` or `1`'s. From that pattern if may be possible to deduce how to build a demultiplexer. Perhaps ... Isn't there a manual for the keyboard describing this btw?

Comment: No, there is no manual for the keyboard, I tried to reach out to the company (Fatar) they only provided the diagram I shared above. The main challenge for me is that I have never done this project where I have to scan keys so im completely new to this area,

Comment: Ok. It's still a cool project to have to figure out how it works. Does the Fatar have a model number? I couldn't see one on the circuit diagram.

Comment: Its the Fatar TP9S - How do I share you the data sheet

Comment: @SaadImtiaz If you have a link to it, you could share that.

Comment: I got it from the fatar company I have the soft copy

Comment: @SaadImtiaz Oh... Perhaps there's a forum for people dealing which that keyboard? I remember searching for it the other day and thought that I saw a lot of discussions regarding Fatar TP/9S

Comment: I made a github repository in it its the datasheet for it (https://github.com/Saad-Imtiaz/Fatar-Keybaord)

Comment: @SaadImtiaz Great - but unfortunately I don't understand how to get the info. Perhaps a forum for people using/building apps around the keyboard is the best chance.

Comment: can you direct me to forum like a link, I couldn't find any where there is a proper solution for this

Comment: @SaadImtiaz I couldn't find one Today although I didn't search very thoroughly. Did you manage to produce the log of all pins when you perform different actions on the keyboard?

Comment: no :( I wasnt , I am completely lost here, looks like its gonna be an abandon project :P

Comment: But ... you _are_ able to read all the digial pins? How many physical pins are there in total (that is connected to the Fatar somehow)? I didn't think about it before, but you seem to use a MIDI class. Doesn't that deliver `Note On` messages? Those should contain the MIDI channel, the _Key_ **and** the _Velocity_.

Comment: yes yes, I am able to read all the pins, there are 16 pins on right and 14 on the left, I am able to play the it without the velocity without any problems

Comment: Ok, let me put it this way: Does more than one pin change state when you press down a key? You'll have to read all of the pins and save their state and print _all_ of the pins states if _any_ state changes. You have 16+14 pins, but the loop `key = 0; key < 49` suggests 49 pins?

Comment: yes exactly , actually all I need is to find a way to scan this keyboard matrix, in a manner that I can calculate the first switch and second switch time difference, I found I code on Git up but I cant set it up for my setting of the keyboard matrix